# These guys, especially Tom, is bad

Tags: singular-vs-plural, punctuation

Which of the following are correct?

(A) These guys, especially Tom, are bad.

(B) These guys, especially Tom, is bad.

(C) These guys (especially Tom) are bad.

I think (A) and (C) are correct, but I'm not quite sure how "especially" affects the "be".

Comment: 'Especially' doesn't affect 'be' in any special way; your instincts seem to be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. 'Especially' doesn't affect the verb. You can see this from the following:

> These guys are bad, especially Tom who is the worst.

or

> These guys, especially Tom who is the worst, are bad.